# how to integrate passport-facebook and jwt without session?

Tags: jwt, passport.js, passport-facebook, express-jwt

I want to use passport-github or facebook login with jwt token, without using saving sessions on the server.
But we have two requests from frontend:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

how to handle the frontend codes?

In normal case, we only have one request

```
axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { email, password })
.then(response => {
  cookie.save('token', response.data.token, { path: '/' });
  dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
  window.location.href = CLIENT_ROOT_URL + '/dashboard';
})
.catch((error) => {
  errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
});
}
```

so we can save the token locally. but for passport-facebook, we have two requests('/auth/facebook' and '/auth/facebook/callback'). So how to save the token locally?

Comment: how to send jwt token to client?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the GET request will not work. You need to use an a link to trigger the /auth/login.

```
<a href="http://localhost:5150/auth/facebook">
```

To send the token to the client, you should redirect to a client page with the jwt stored in cookie.

```
const token = user.generateJwt();
res.cookie("auth", token);
return res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/socialauthredirect`);
```

and at the client landing page extract the jwt and save it to local storage.

```
class SocialAuthRedirect extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(
      fbAuthUser(getCookie("auth"), () => {
        document.cookie =
          "auth=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
        this.props.history.push("/profile");
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```